# Exide battery manufacture date

Tags: battery

I can't understand the date of manufacturing of an Exide battery EC440.
The code is **8AE12-1** but I can't find this kind of code in the Exide table.
Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.exidebatteries.com.au/battery-faq/), it looks like Exide uses different coding schemes for their batteries depending on what country you're in. The chart is currently found about two-thirds of the way down the page. Yours might be the Korean code with an additional digit, or it might be a Portugal or Philippines code,  but without knowing where it was made it's difficult to say. If the country is listed on the battery, you may be able to find the correct code from this table.

```
COUNTRY   DIGITS      LOCATIONS   REGIME      EXPLANATION
Australia   9         Top         DDMMMYYTTTT D=Day of Month (02=2nd) 
Philippines 7         Top         YMMDDPS     M=Month (A-L > E=May) 
Korea       5         Top         FPYMD       MM=Month (07=July) 
USA         10        Back side   FPSMMMDDYY  MMM=Month(Oct=October) 
Portugal    7         Top         YMMDDPS     Y=Year (14=2014)
```

Keep in mind that these coding schemes are created by the manufacturers for their own internal use, and are not based on any common standard. They could also be changed at any time.